# All possible permutations of 2 vectors on rust

Tags: rust, combinations, permutation, data-generation

Good afternoon. I have 2 vectors of unequal length

```
let names = vec!["Marie", "Jana", "Eva", "Anna"];
let surnames = vec!["Novakova", "Svobodova", "Novotna", "Dvorakova", "Kralova"];
```

How can I go through all the possible combinations of first and last names ?

Conditional 3 vector I want to get:

```
let gen_full_name = vec!["Marie Novakova", "Jana Novakova", "Eva Novotna", "Anna Novotna", "Jana Novakova", ...];
```

Comment: Just use a nested iteration? Or `itertools::cartesian_product`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let names = vec!["Marie", "Jana", "Eva", "Anna"];
let surnames = vec!["Novakova", "Svobodova", "Novotna", "Dvorakova", "Kralova"];
let mut full_names = Vec::with_capacity(names.len() * surnames.len());
for name in &names {
    for surname in &surnames {
        full_names.push(format!("{} {}", name, surname));
    }
}
println!("{:?}", full_names);
```

No unnecessary allocations required.

Comment: I wish I could give more than "+1" because sometimes simple is just easier for everybody to understand.  95% of the people who have done more than "hello world" in _any_ programming language would understand your answer.  Not so for functional-based approaches.

Answer (score 2):

This is a approach using a functional programming style.

```rust
let names = vec!["Marie", "Jana", "Eva", "Anna"];
let surnames = vec!["Novakova", "Svobodova", "Novotna", "Dvorakova", "Kralova"];
let combinations = names.iter()
    // First, map all firstnames `n` to a list containing
    // a combination of this firstname with every lastname
    .map(|&n| 
        // For every firstname, the surnames are iterated
        surnames.iter()
            // For every surname iteration, the firstname and lastname are
            // combined into a single string 
            .map(move |&s| format!("{} {}", &n, &s))
            .collect::<Vec<_>>())
    // the lists are seperated for every first name so far.
    // last but not least they must be joined together.
    .fold(vec![], |mut v, mut dat| { v.append(&mut dat); v} );
```